# show that a continuous map $f: [0,1) \to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous iff there is continuous $g: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ that agrees with $f$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

show that a continuous function $f: [0,1) \to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous iff there is $g: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ a continuous function that agrees with $f$ on $[0,1)$.

I am not sure how I would proceed for the forward direction. The backward direction is obvious, since if such $g$ exists, then the compactness of $[0,1]$ would imply the uniform continuity of $g$ and hence $f$. I was considering taking the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $1$, but I wasn't sure how to use the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous. What if $f$ is just continuous and not uniformly continuous?

Comment: The obstruction to doing what you suggest is that $\lim_{x\to 1} f (x)$ might not exist since $f $ might diverge to $\pm\infty $, which is why you need uniform continuity

Comment: To see why you need more that continuity, take $f (x)=\frac{1}{x-1} $.

Comment: Thanks. Could you write your complete rigorous solution below as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $f: [0,1) \to \mathbb R$ be uniformly continuous.

(*Motivation:* We want to show that $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ exists. It is clear that we cannot determine the actual limit. That is an indicator that the
[*completeness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space)
of the real numbers might be helpful: It guarantees the convergence
of Cauchy sequences without making a statement about the limit.)

For any  sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $[0,1)$ with $x_n \to 1$, 
$(f(x_n))_n$ is a *Cauchy sequence* and therefore convergent.

It follows that $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ exists, so that $g:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$
defined by
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
 f(x)& \text{for } 0 \le x < 1 \\
 \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) & \text{for } x = 1
 \end{cases}
$$
is continuous.